# Unable to select certain fields in MongoDB (Mongoose) result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've ran into a bit of an odd issue with a mongoose result. I can select one value from the object, but not another.

For example I'm calling

```js
Product.find({"name": {$regex: search), '$options': 'i'}})
            .select('dropDate storePrice totalLikes')
            .limit(1)
            .exec((err, product) => {
                if (err) console.log('[ERROR] Unable to get product. ', err)
                console.log('Product found is: ', product)
                console.log('storePrice is: ', product[0].storePrice)
                console.log('dropDate is: ', product[0].dropDate)
                console.log('totalLikes is: ', product[0].totalLikes)
                resolve(product)
            })
```

I get a result and im console logging out the entire product. The result is:

```json
Product found is:  [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("614f5c8f4b004b4d4dc82e4f"),
    storePrice: 6.99,
    dropDate: 2021-08-21T15:00:00.000Z,
    totalLikes: 2158
  }
]
```

I can log out the storePrice field

```
storePrice is:  6.99
```

However if I try to log out the dropDate and totalLikes fields I get undefined

```
drop date is:  undefined
totalLikes is:  undefined
```

Any ideas why these fields are returning undefined when i try to access them? Even though they exist in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Mongoose by default hydrate the documents returned, so they are not pure JavaScript objects.

If you want to return pure JavaScript objects, you should add `.lean()` to your query. That will in addition increase the performance:

```js
Product.find({"name": {$regex: search), '$options': 'i'}})
            .select('dropDate storePrice totalLikes')
            .limit(1)
            .lean()
```

You can find more info in the [official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by stringifying and then parsing it again, really odd.